# SQL Query Select and Update

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, alias

Hello i'm trying to make an update with a select statement.
Here is my code

> update recolha_hrs_2014 r set r.state = 'porval' from (select e.sigla
>   from dgrhe_entidade e) where r.state = 'finalizado' and r.qzp = '10'
>   and e.sigla = '145014'

However it gives me an error. 
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 3: from (select e.sigla from dgrhe_entidade e)

Any suggestion. What am i doing wrong?

Hope you can help me
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update r
set set r.state = 'porval'
from recolha_hrs_2014 r
inner join dgrhe_entidade e on e.??? = r.????
where r.state = 'finalizado' and r.qzp = '10' and e.sigla = '145014'
```

I'm not sure which field(s) in dgrhe_entidade  map to recolha_hrs_2014, but that's what needs to go in: "e.??? = r.????"